# Reading and renaming multiple fields with the same name with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Basically what I have, is a PDF with form fields created with Copy/Pasting (over 700 of them :/ ). The problem is, Acrobat lets all fields with the same name have the same value. This is a problem, where I'd like each field to have a unique value. (The Acrobat software does not provide any solutions other than renaming all 700 fields manually)

I've Googled around and found a C# library, iTextSharp. And I need some help using it, a search of Google didn't return much answers...

This code returns only ONE field, which is the field that I have Copy/Pasted... Not the individual fields.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("p31.pdf");
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Test Out.pdf", FileMode.Create)) {
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs);
            AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;

            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, AcroFields.Item> kpv in fields.Fields)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(kpv.Key);
            }

            stamper.Close();
        }
```

How do I get EACH FIELD INDIVIDUALLY and then rename them? Thanks

Comment: If they have the same name, they **are** the same field, merely different visualizations of it. That's why Adobe and itext handle it so. That being said, while AcroFields allows you to handle all of them as a single field only, more low-level methods allow you to change the names by direct PDF object manipulation.

Comment: Yes, +1 for Michael. This is only possible by manipulation at the lowest level. This can only be done by somebody who's PDF fu is great, so please don't ask "Can you give me code sample?" You'll have to hire somebody to do this, or start reading ISO-32000-1.

Answer (score 0):

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("OriginalPDF");
PdfCopyFields copier = new PdfCopyFields(new FileStream("NewPDF", FileMode.Create));
int doc = 0;
foreach ( var item in reader.AcroFields.Fields )
  if ( item.Key.IndexOf("NameField") != -1 )
    reader.AcroFields.RenameField(item.Key, "NameField" + ( doc++ ));
 copier.AddDocument(reader, "1");   



 //Now you have finalPDF wiith Namefield1,Namefield2,Namefield3....
```

Comment: If you read the question more thoroughly, you'll see that the OP wanted something entirely different. He did not want to prevent the creation of duplicate field names which your code does. He had a PDF in which there already were many fields with duplicate names, and he wanted to de-duplicate them after the fact.